# vncserver command is not creating port in CentOS 7 ( It is getting killed immediately )

Tags: centos-7, vncserver, tigervnc

**While executing `vncserver` command getting below output but, no port is listing while trying `vncserver -list` command.**

```
[user1@localhost ~]$ vncserver 
New 'localhost.localdomain:55 (user1)' desktop is localhost.localdomain:55
Starting applications specified in /home/user1/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/user1/.vnc/localhost.localdomain:55.log
```

[user1@localhost ~]$ vncserver -list

```
TigerVNC server sessions:

X DISPLAY # PROCESS ID
[user1@localhost ~]$
```

**Log says that it is killing newly created port:**

```
[user1@localhost ~]$ cat /home/user1/.vnc/localhost.localdomain:56.log

Xvnc TigerVNC 1.8.0 - built Aug  9 2019 03:04:19
Copyright (C) 1999-2017 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 12001000, The X.Org Foundation


Sat Nov 27 21:13:18 2021
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5956
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
/home/user1/.vnc/xstartup: line 5: 31982 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
Killing Xvnc process ID 31890
```

**`xstartup` file under `~/vnc` folder is shown below**

```
[user1@localhost ~]$ cat ~/.vnc/xstartup 
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
# Assume either Gnome or KDE will be started by default when installed
# We want to kill the session automatically in this case when user logs out. In case you modify
# /etc/X11/xinit/Xclients or ~/.Xclients yourself to achieve a different result, then you should
# be responsible to modify below code to avoid that your session will be automatically killed
if [ -e /usr/bin/gnome-session -o -e /usr/bin/startkde ]; then
    vncserver -kill $DISPLAY
fi
```

**My Observation:**
If I comment `vncserver -kill $DISPLAY` in `xstartup` file, port is not getting killed. But while connecting via  VNC Viewer it shows black screen.

Comment: One alternate option I done is `switched from GNOME to Xfce`

Answer (score 0):

TigerVNC server installed in CentOS 7 will try two desktop servers:

1. gnome-classic-session
2. KDE

Gnome is usually preinstalled in your system, but not the **classic** desktop. However, VNC log will not notice you the lack of this component.
You may try to `yum install gnome-classic-session` and re-run your `vncserver`, see if the problem remains.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

gnome desktop `dbus` setting `max_connections_per_user`

```
vim /etc/dbus-1/system.conf

<busconfig>
  <limit name="max_connections_per_user">100000</limit>
</busconfig>
```

Comment: You mean we need to alter this settings ?